# Substitute value with value label in DGV

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, dataset

***Initial Position:***
I have bound a typed Dataset (populated with data from sql query) to a DGV. The DGV entries are not for editing just for reading. The DGV has 12 rows (Months).

***Problem:***
Now I am trying to display the months names instead of the numbers you could say I want to label the values (1 = January, 2 = February etc.) but dont know how to do it.

***What I tried:***
My idea was to create and use an unbound table (values; months names) but I cannot find an column-type (DGV -> Edit Columns) that could perform what I want.

EDIT: 
Hello, no, it is not about the header. I give you an example.

ATM it looks like:

```
1|true|
2|false|
3|false|
```

...
My goal is:

```
January|true|
Feburary|false|
March|false|
```

Comment: if you are talking about the headers: `dgv.columns(n).HeaderText` will allow you to change it

Comment: Hi. no it is not about the header. I edited my post to give you an example.

Comment: DateSet supports DataRelation  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=dataset%20datarelation%20object&emptyWatermark=true&searchButtonTooltip=Search%20MSDN&ac=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try the event "CellFormating". In web it would be simple since there is an event raised after each row data bound, but not in windows form unfortunately.

I suggest that you change the value of the month directly in the CellFormating event as follow :

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    If e.Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso IsNumeric(e.Value) Then
        e.Value = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(e.Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

I just tested this code and works perfectly.

Comment: Great!That is a good way handeling that. Since my values are in column 1 i just had to set the enviroment: If e.ColumnIndex() = 1 Then ... End If and everything works great!